# How do I loop through all open background view contexts and perform a save?

Tags: swift, core-data, viewcontext

I have a program that concurrently reads the data from 3 separate CSV files into 3 separate background view contexts all based on the same persistent container.  Once the data has been inserted into the view contexts I use a series of `if` statements to test if changes have been made, and if so, save the view contexts to the common persistent store.  The program works.  But it seems to me that I should be able to query core data for a listing of these view contexts and then in turn loop through them and perform the save, simplifying the code.  Unfortunately I have been unable to determine how to do it.  Below is a subset of my code which is all contained within the same view model class.

```
let BGContext1 = persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()
let BGContext2 = persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()
let BGContext3 = persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()

... code that loads view contexts with data via withTaskGroup

if BGContext1.hasChanges {
    do {
        try BGContext1.save()
    } catch {
        print("error saving \(error)")
    }
}
if BGContext2.hasChanges {
    do {
        try BGContext2.save()
    } catch {
        print("error saving \(error)")
    }
}
if BGContext3.hasChanges {
    do {
        try BGContext3.save()
    } catch {
        print("error saving \(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not keep them in your own array property and loop over it?

Comment: What determine that the data has been inserted? Why not just do a save after the parsing of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Larme is correct.  Putting the save functionality into my parsing function works.  Since then, I learned that you can save the CSV data directly into Core Data i.e. an SQLite file with a batch insert.  Below is the function that performs the batch insert.  This eliminates having to perform a save on the view contexts and its is very fast.

```
func CSVtoCoreData(latestDate: Date, bgContext: NSManagedObjectContext) async {
    bgContext.performAndWait {
        var arrayOfDict: [[String:Any]] = []
        var data: String = ""
        do {
            data = try String(contentsOfFile: filePath)
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return
        }
        var rows = data.components(separatedBy: "\n")
        rows.removeFirst()
        for row in rows {
            let columns = row.components(separatedBy: ",")
            let tempDate = columns[0].replacingOccurrences(of: "/", with: "")
            let tempTimeStamp = stringToDateFormatterWSJ.date(from: tempDate)!
            let close = Float(columns[4].replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: ""))!
            
            let newRecord: [String:Any] = [
                "fundName": fundName,
                "id": UUID(),
                "timeStamp": tempTimeStamp,
                "close": close
            ]
            arrayOfDict.append(newRecord)
        }
        let insertRequest = NSBatchInsertRequest(entity: TradingDayClose.entity(), objects: arrayOfDict)
        bgContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy
        _ = try? bgContext.execute(insertRequest) as? NSBatchInsertResult
    }
}
```